# How to slice strings inside tuples inside lists?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working with an SQL database to get a list of primary key ids, however when I print the list, it prints an extra comma along with it. Is there a way to remove or access just the numbers in the list?

Here is what I have:

```
import mysql.connector

con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                              database='database',
                              user='root',
                              password=database_pw)
cursor = con.cursor()
query = """select playerid from nba_players;"""
cursor.execute(query)
playerids = cursor.fetchall()
print(playerids)
```

Here is the output:

```
[(20000441,),
 (20000442,),
 (20000443,),
 (20000452,),
 (20000453,),
 (20000455,),
 (20000456,),
 (20000457,),
 (20000466,),
 (20000468,),
 (20000471,),
 (20000474,),
 (20000482,),
 (20000483,),
 (20000485,),
 (20000486,),
 (20000492,),
 (20000497,),
 (20000500,),
 (20000515,),
 (20000516,),
 (20000517,),
 (20000522,),
 (20000539,),
 (20000544,),
...
```

And here is the output that I'm looking for

```
[(20000441),
 (20000442),
 (20000443),
 (20000452),
 (20000453),
 (20000455),
 (20000456),
 (20000457),
 (20000466),
 (20000468),
 (20000471),
 (20000474),
 (20000482),
 (20000483),
 (20000485),
 (20000486),
 (20000492),
 (20000497),
 (20000500),
 (20000515),
 (20000516),
 (20000517),
 (20000522),
 (20000539),
 (20000544),
...
```

Comment: `new_list = [item[0] for item in playerids]` will give you a flat list instead of a list of one-member tuples, which is what you're starting with.

Comment: BTW, these are not strings.

Comment: The trailing commas, in python, represent that it is a tuple with just one value. You can not actually get rid of them, unless you only want to store the numbers in the list (without them being in tuples themselves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
[playerid[0] for playerid in playerids]
```